# How to select an element where attribute opacity is 1 with jQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes, opacity

I have these elements, and I need to select the li inside the ul where opacity=1.
How can I do this?

```
<ul class="class" id="ul">
                <li style="width: 100%; list-style: none outside none; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 98; opacity: 0;"><a title="title1" href=""><img alt="alt" class="class_name" src="/images/7dfc294d5c3bcebecb2ec0e44fd27d1c.jpg"></a></li>
                <li style="width: 100%; list-style: none outside none; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 98; opacity: 0;"><a title="title2" href=""><img alt="alt" class="class_name " src="/images/a9c9eb42934df4576b352d88f607f292.jpg"></a></li>
                <li style="width: 100%; list-style: none outside none; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 98; opacity: 0;"><a title="title3" href=""><img alt="alt" class="class_name " src="/images/b64264692c0d648068c9d1380e9099c1.jpg"></a></li>
                <li style="width: 100%; list-style: none outside none; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 99; opacity: 1;"><a title="title4" href=""><img alt="alt" class="class_name " src="/images/43e3e5e2edc4234ecddbc89636e4e224.jpg"></a></li>
                <li style="width: 100%; list-style: none outside none; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 98; opacity: 0;"><a title="title5" href=""><img alt="e-alt" class="class_name " src="/images/31a156ce7f7ab5485366d24f6cbfbede.jpg"></a></li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$('#ul li').filter(function() {
  return $(this).css('opacity') == '1';
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/368/)**

You can also try with `.each()`

```
var lis = [];
$('#ul li').each(function() {
    if ($(this).css('opacity') == '1') {
        lis.push(this);
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/369/)**

or using `.map()`

```
var lis = $('#ul li').map(function() {
    if($(this).css('opacity') == '1')
        return this;
}).get();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/370/)**

Comment: Does this work with IE's `filter` CSS rule as well? Setting opacity does, but does getting work too?

Comment: ops my bad I had a problem with loading jQuery thats why I had null error. It works

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$('li[style*="opacity: 1"]')
```

but I'm not sure if it will return the elements when there's no space, like `opacity:1`

Comment: it sais Error: $("li[style*=\"opacity: 1\"]") is null